# Python script to convert JSON to XLSX in Azure Function

Tags: python, json, excel, azure-functions

I tried parsing the JSON in query parameter (URL) in my Azure Function that converts JSON into XLSX and stores it in the storage container, but there is an error with the code which I am not able to solve. Given below is the Error Code.

> File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 114, in arrays_to_mgr index = _extract_index(arrays) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 667, in _extract_index raise ValueError("If using all scalar values, you must pass an index")

Here is the code I am using currently, please do let me know where am I going wrong here!

```
import logging
import os
import json
import pandas as pd
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

# Retrieve JSON data from query parameters
json_data = req.params.get("json_data")

if not json_data:
    return func.HttpResponse("Error: 'json_data' parameter is missing.", status_code=400)

# Parse the JSON data
try:
    json_data = json.loads(json_data)
except json.JSONDecodeError:
    return func.HttpResponse("Error: Invalid JSON data.", status_code=400)

# Create a DataFrame from the JSON data
df = pd.DataFrame(json_data)

# Specify the output XLSX file path
xlsx_file_path = '/tmp/output.xlsx'

# Convert the DataFrame to an XLSX file
df.to_excel(xlsx_file_path, index=False)

# Azure Blob Storage settings
STORAGEACCOUNTURL = MY_URL
STORAGEACCOUNTKEY = MY_KEY
CONTAINERNAME = 'demo'
BLOBNAME = 'output.xlsx'

# Create a BlobServiceClient to work with Blob Storage
blob_service_client_instance = BlobServiceClient(account_url=STORAGEACCOUNTURL, credential=STORAGEACCOUNTKEY)

# Get a container client
container_client = blob_service_client_instance.get_container_client(CONTAINERNAME)

# Upload the XLSX file to the container
with open(xlsx_file_path, mode="rb") as data:
    blob_client = container_client.upload_blob(name=BLOBNAME, data=data, overwrite=True)

return func.HttpResponse(f'Success: Converted and uploaded {BLOBNAME}')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Had made some changes in your code, the pd.DataFrame() constructor is expecting an index for your DataFrame when it's being created from the JSON data.

The code expects json_data to be a valid JSON array of objects in the query parameter. Each object within the array will be treated as a row in the resulting Excel file.

**Working Code -**

```
import logging
import os
import json
import pandas as pd
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    # Retrieve JSON data from query parameters
    json_data = req.params.get("json_data")

    if not json_data:
        return func.HttpResponse("Error: 'json_data' parameter is missing.", status_code=400)

    # Parse the JSON data as a JSON array
    try:
        json_data = json.loads(json_data)
    except json.JSONDecodeError:
        return func.HttpResponse("Error: Invalid JSON data.", status_code=400)

    # Create a DataFrame from the JSON array
    df = pd.DataFrame(json_data)

    # Specify the output XLSX file path
    xlsx_file_path = '/tmp/output.xlsx'

    # Convert the DataFrame to an XLSX file
    df.to_excel(xlsx_file_path, index=False)

    # Azure Blob Storage settings
    STORAGEACCOUNTURL = 'https://your-storage-account.blob.core.windows.net'
    STORAGEACCOUNTKEY = 'your-storage-account-key'
    CONTAINERNAME = 'your-container-name'
    BLOBNAME = 'output.xlsx'

    # Create a BlobServiceClient to work with Blob Storage
    blob_service_client_instance = BlobServiceClient(account_url=STORAGEACCOUNTURL, credential=STORAGEACCOUNTKEY)

    # Get a container client
    container_client = blob_service_client_instance.get_container_client(CONTAINERNAME)

    # Upload the XLSX file to the container
    with open(xlsx_file_path, mode="rb") as data:
        blob_client = container_client.upload_blob(name=BLOBNAME, data=data, overwrite=True)

    return func.HttpResponse(f'Success: Converted and uploaded {BLOBNAME}')
```

**Output -**

[Output Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWMgE.png)